# INotifyPropertyChanged dont fire when modify value of a dictonnary

Tags: c#, mvvm

My view :

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:TacheGroupeViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
...
<CheckBox x:Name="InProgress" 
  Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CmdInProgress, ElementName=WindowMain}"
  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
/>
```

My ViewModel :

```
class TacheGroupeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

        #region MVVM Patern Logic
        public Model.TaskGroupes TaskGroupe { get; set; }
        public TacheGroupeViewModel() {
            Update();
        }
        public void Update() {
            this.TaskGroupe = new Model.TaskGroupes();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion

public ICommand CmdInProgress {
    get {
        return this._cmdInProgress ?? ( this._cmdInProgress = new RelayCommand(x => {checkBTN(x); }) );
    }
}

private void checkBTN(object tache) {
    var task = (Task)tache;
    var TaskUI = this.TachesGroupes.GroupesConfig.SelectMany(s => s.Value.Tasks).Where(...)FirstOrDefault();
    //TaskUI is a task Object
    TaskUI.ModifInProgress = !TaskUI.ModifInProgress; // Why View dont Update
}
```

The class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Why when I change the prop `ModifInProgress`, the prop dont change and the `RaisePropertyChanged` isn't fired ?

Comment: What is `TaskUI`? And how is the `ModifInProgress` property declared? Where is the dictionary you mentioned in the title?

Comment: *"when I change the prop "ModifInProgress", the prop dont change"* - what do you mean be *"the prop don't change"*? Do you explicitly set the property using `ModifInProgress = ...` and still the value isn't set? Check the property's setter than.